# Chrome Tab Grid Layout can no longer be disabled via chrome://flags, is there another way?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I used to be able to disable Google Chrome on android from having the Tabs Grid, by disabling the flag.

That no longer seems to have any effect. Is there another way to change this setting?

[image: chrome flags page, with all Tab related flags, including the grid layout, disabled.]

Answer (score 1):

Doing some more research, I find that [this is no longer enough](http://laptopmag.com/uk/news/how-to-turn-off-the-new-grid-tab-layout-for-chrome-on-android)

Update: That used to be it, but with the most recent update Google broke this fix, but never fear there is a temporary solution to make it work again.

1. Type `chrome://flags/#temporary-unexpire-flags-m88` into the address bar
2. Tap on the drop-down menu in the Tab Grid Layout entry
3. Select "Enabled"
4. Tap the Relaunch button at the bottom of the screen

I suspect that will only be a temporary solution though.